# ASP.Net WebForms running mulitple queries at the same time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, updatepanel

This is for an enterprise web application.

We are building a front page/dashboard that queries our database for live statistics. The page has 3 update panels, each update panel has a user control that pulls data for it's box. Lets call the user controls UC_NotStarted, UC_Active and UC_Finished.

We have built the queries that return the data and all of them take a while to run (~7 seconds each). So if we let the first page run with one update panel the image spins for ~21 seconds and display everything.  We have broken that code into 3 update panels and set the loading to conditional. When we do this we get one box to load every 7 seconds. That’s a step in the right direction but they load sequentially (UC_NotStarted is queried waits 7 seconds and displays, then UC_Active goes for 7 seconds, and finally UC_Finished runs for 7 seconds). We are still at 21 seconds but data is being shown every 7 seconds.

We would like all of the data to be shown in 7 seconds since all of the update panels should be fetching the data at the same time. Instead of using LinqToSQL to pull the data I am now leaning towards web services to get it but not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), specifically the [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx) method. It's quite possible with this to run the 3 queries simultaneously and sit in a `Thread.Sleep` loop waiting for all three to finish executing so you can update all relevant parts of the page.

The following code will almost certainly require tweaking but would give you a rough idea of how to do this:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public bool Completed;
    public DataTable Result;
    public int ResultId;
}

public void GetData()
{
    var QueryResults = new List<QueryResult>();
    queryResults.Add(new QueryResult() { ResultId = 1 });
    queryResults.Add(new QueryResult() { ResultId = 2 });
    queryResults.Add(new QueryResult() { ResultId = 3 });

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(QueryRoutine), queryResults[0]);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(QueryRoutine), queryResults[1]);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(QueryRoutine), queryResults[2]);

    var completedResults = new List<QueryResult>();
    while(QueryResults.Count > 0)
    {
        for(int 1 = QueryResults.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--;)
        {
            if (queryResults[i].Completed)
            {
                completedResults.Add(queryResults[i]);
                queryResults.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    // All background threads have completed, do something with the results,
    // return them to the front-end, etc,..
}

public void QueryRoutine(object qR)
{
    var queryResult = (QueryResult)qR;

    // perform long running query here on a distinct thread, as QueryRoutine 
    // is now being run on three separate threads by the calls to QueueUserWorkItem
    // based on queryResult.ResultId picking the relevant query for values 
    // of 1, 2 or 3

    queryResult.Completed = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks interesting. I'm going to try to get this working in our site this week and I'll report how it turns out.